# vue component data not changing in method

Tags: vue.js, methods, vue-component

I have a Vue component favourite button for a product. The button has an image. I want to change the image if the product is already a favourite. This is all checked in the back-end and works.

My problem is that `this.route` won't change in the `checkfav` method.

Component button with image `src` set to `"route"`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="button-favourite" v-bind:value="product" @click="setFav">
            <img :src="route" alt="favourite button" class="user-image user-image--small">
        </button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Component script:

```js
export default {
  created() {
    this.checkFav()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      route: '/storage/icons/heart.png',
    }
  },
  props: ['product', 'user'],
  methods: {
    setFav() {
      axios
        .post(`../api/fav`, {
          product: this.product,
          user: this.user,
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data), this.checkFav()
        })
    },
    checkFav() {
      axios
        .post(`../api/checkfav`, {
          product: this.product,
          user: this.user,
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data == 'true') {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.route = '/storage/icons/fullheart.png'
          } else {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.route = '/storage/icons/heart.png'
          }
          //console.log(response.data);
        })
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: what does `console.log(response.data)` say?

Comment: ```console.log(response.data)``` says: true

Comment: Looks good to me. Maybe check `console.log(this.route)` in `checkFav.then` to see if the value is actually updating.

Comment: I tried that and the result gave the original route. so it didn't update.

Comment: Check the type of your `response.data` and see whether your condition `response.data == 'true'` is evaluated correctly. Normally you want to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I just got the same conclusion the response.data is a string so I have changed it to ```=``` instead of ```==``` thanks for all the help.

Comment: `=` and `==` are completely different things though. `=` will assign the value and `==` will loosely compare the values.

Comment: To avoid using routes like `../api/fav`, with axios you can set `baseURL`. Check the docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance). Once you create the instance, you can assign it to `Vue.prototype.$http = axiosInstance`, and then use it as `this.$http.get()` in your components

Answer (score 0):

try to use beforeMounted hook, or write let `self = this` and set route by self.route = response.data